# Briefing Alarm News and Weather Not Read Aloud on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, alarm, text-to-speech

I've got an alarm set daily on my Galaxy S3 with the briefing alarm type selected in my  alarm's settings with all three briefing content items selected (weather, today's schedule, and news).

However, when the alarm begins, it shows the weather, today's schedule, and news onscreen, it plays a brief melody, then it plays the alarm sound I used previously (ticktac alarm), when it should be speaking the items aloud.

I've tried rebooting the phone and deleting and recreating the alarm, but I cannot get the phone to speak the items aloud.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked your device's TTS settings? It might have trouble with the voice engine, or with the language being configured.

Answer (score 1):

With the tip from [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy), I was able to determine that the problem was that I didn't have `Samsung TTS` as my preferred TTS engine.

To fix this, go to `Settings > Language and input > Text-to-speech output`, and you can select `Samsung TTS` there (mine was set to `Google Text-to-speech Engine`).

EDIT

Well, I was mistaken apparently.  My alarm has reverted back to showing the news and weather and playing my old alarm.  I'm assuming this is a bug at this point, unless someone can find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Select driving mode in settings

Comment: Could you expand your answer and explain how to do this? Just from your answer, I do not know what you are suggesting.